# Autenticacion con jsowebtoken

Tags: nodejs, webtoken

Tengo una aplicación que en el `backend` funciona con `nodeJS`, en el mismo controlo bien el proceso de autenticarse bien, el problema lo tengo en el `frontend` , yo uso token para la autenticar y en el `frontend` lo guardo en el `LocalStorage` del navegador, pero no se como introducirlo en el `header` para luego en el backend obtenerlo en un `middleware`.

*Gracias de antemano... Salu2s*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la especificación, el token debe ir en la cabecera `Authorization`. Para no hacer repetitivo el proceso puedes hacer una función utilitaria que te prepare las peticiones:

```
export const $http = (path, { method, query, body }) => {
  /* Accept y Content-Type solo son necesarios si vas a trabajar con una API basada en JSON */
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  };

  /* URL construction */
  let _url = `<URL a tu endpoint>/${path}`;

  Object.keys(query || {}).forEach((key) => {
    _url += `${key}=${query[key]}&`;
  });

  /* Request payload */
  const requestBody = {
    method: method || 'GET',
    headers,
  };

  if (method === 'POST' || method === 'PUT') {
    requestBody.body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return fetch(_url, requestBody);
};
```

De modo que la uses de la siguiente manera por ejemplo:

```
export const create = async (data) => {
  const res = await $http('/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  });
  return res.json();
};
```

Obviamente en lugar de [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) puedes usar librerías como [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). En el backend solo debes escribir un middleware para tu servidor que obtenga la cabecera `Authorization` y compruebe si existe o es válido el token.